# What would the most efficient way be to draw a pixel using turtle in Python?

Tags: python, pixel, turtle-graphics, python-turtle, coding-efficiency

If I were to draw, let's say, a pixel art of Mario for example, with a lot of squares (see pixel art below), what would the most efficient way be to do this? I've tried it, but the code is very long, even cutting it down with functions to the best of my ability.

[Mario Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9uc0.png)

Here is my code, it works, but is not very efficient:

```
import turtle
from turtle import *

speed(0)


def redSquare():
    fillcolor("red")
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        forward(30)
        right(90)
    end_fill()


def blueSquare():
    fillcolor("royalblue")
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        forward(30)
        right(90)
    end_fill()


def yellowSquare():
    fillcolor("yellow")
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        forward(30)
        right(90)
    end_fill()


def skinSquare():
    fillcolor("sandybrown")
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        forward(30)
        right(90)
    end_fill()


def brownSquare():
    fillcolor("saddlebrown")
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        forward(30)
        right(90)
    end_fill()


def blackSquare():
    fillcolor("black")
    begin_fill()
    for i in range(4):
        forward(30)
        right(90)
    end_fill()


penup()
goto(100, -150)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(70, -150)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(40, -150)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(10, -150)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(10, -120)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(40, -120)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(70, -120)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(40, -90)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(10, -90)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, -90)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, -60)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, -60)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(10, -60)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(40, -60)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(70, -60)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(100, -60)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(100, -30)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(70, -30)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(40, -30)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(10, -30)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, -30)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, -30)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 0)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, 0)
pendown()
yellowSquare()

penup()
goto(10, 0)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(40, 0)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(70, 0)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(100, 0)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(100, 30)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(70, 30)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(40, 30)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(10, 30)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, 30)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 30)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 60)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, 60)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(10, 60)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(40, 60)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(70, 60)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(10, 90)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, 90)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 90)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 120)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 120)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, 120)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(10, 120)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(40, 120)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(70, 120)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(100, 150)
pendown()
blackSquare()

penup()
goto(70, 150)
pendown()
blackSquare()

penup()
goto(40, 150)
pendown()
blackSquare()

penup()
goto(10, 150)
pendown()
blackSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, 150)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 150)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 180)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, 180)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(10, 180)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(40, 180)
pendown()
blackSquare()

penup()
goto(70, 180)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(100, 180)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(130, 180)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(100, 210)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(70, 210)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(40, 210)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(10, 210)
pendown()
blackSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, 210)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 210)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 240)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, 240)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(10, 240)
pendown()
blackSquare()

penup()
goto(40, 240)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(100, 270)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(70, 270)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(40, 270)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(10, 270)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, 270)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 270)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-50, 300)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-20, 300)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(10, 300)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, 300)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, 300)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, 300)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, 270)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, 270)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, 270)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, 270)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, 240)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, 240)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, 240)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, 240)
pendown()
skinSquare()


penup()
goto(-80, 210)
pendown()
skinSquare()


penup()
goto(-110, 210)
pendown()
skinSquare()


penup()
goto(-140, 210)
pendown()
brownSquare()


penup()
goto(-170, 210)
pendown()
skinSquare()


penup()
goto(-200, 210)
pendown()
brownSquare()


penup()
goto(-200, 180)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, 180)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, 180)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, 180)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, 180)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, 180)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, 150)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, 150)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, 150)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, 150)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-200, 150)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, 120)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, 120)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, 120)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, 90)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, 90)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, 90)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, 90)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-200, 60)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, 60)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, 60)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, 60)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, 60)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, 30)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, 30)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, 30)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, 30)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-200, 30)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-230, 30)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-230, 0)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-200, 0)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, 0)
pendown()
redSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, 0)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, 0)
pendown()
yellowSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, 0)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, -30)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, -30)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, -30)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, -30)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-200, -30)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-230, -30)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-230, -60)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-200, -60)
pendown()
skinSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, -60)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, -60)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, -60)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-80, -60)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-110, -90)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, -90)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, -90)
pendown()
blueSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, -120)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, -120)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-200, -120)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-230, -150)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-200, -150)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-170, -150)
pendown()
brownSquare()

penup()
goto(-140, -150)
pendown()
brownSquare()

exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what would the most efficient way be to do this?

I agree with @martineau's general approach (+1) but since you want the most efficient way, I'd change a few things.  I'd use *stamping* instead of *drawing* to reduce the amount of code and speed it up.  I'd also use strings of letters to represent the color pixels instead of arrays of integers.  And I'd store the image upside up instead of upside down.  I find this makes it easier to enter the image as a touch typist and makes it easier to visualize the image even in the encoded form.  And I'd throw `tracer()` at the problem:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

PIXEL_SIZE = 30
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

COLORS = {
    'B': 'blue',
    'K': 'black',
    'O': 'orange',
    'R': 'red',
    'T': 'brown',
    'W': 'white',
    'Y': 'yellow',
}

PIXELS = [
    "WWWRRRRRRWWWW",
    "WWRRRRRRRRRRW",
    "WWTTTOOOKOWWW",
    "WTOTOOOOKOOOW",
    "WTOTTOOOOKOOO",
    "WTTOOOOOKKKKW",
    "WWWOOOOOOOOWW",
    "WWRRBRRRRWWWW",
    "WRRRBRRBRRRWW",
    "RRRRBBBBRRRRW",
    "OORBYBBYBROOW",
    "OOOBBBBBBOOOW",
    "OOBBBBBBBBOOW",
    "WWBBBWWBBBWWW",
    "WTTTWWWWTTTWW",
    "TTTTWWWWTTTTW",
]

WIDTH, HEIGHT = len(PIXELS[0]), len(PIXELS)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup((WIDTH + 3) * PIXEL_SIZE, (HEIGHT + 3) * PIXEL_SIZE)
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.shape('square')
turtle.shapesize(PIXEL_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)
turtle.penup()

x0 = -WIDTH/2 * PIXEL_SIZE
y0 = HEIGHT/2 * PIXEL_SIZE

for i, row in enumerate(PIXELS):
    turtle.setposition(x0, y0 - i * PIXEL_SIZE)

    for pixel in row:
        turtle.color(COLORS[pixel])
        turtle.stamp()
        turtle.forward(PIXEL_SIZE)

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

This approach even works for literal pixels: [image]

Comment: I agree, using `turtle.stamp()` is probably one of the faster if not fastest ways to draw the pixels with `turtle`. You've also made a number of other useful enhancement to my post — so your answer gets my vote.

Comment: Thank you so much for this great response! I am a beginner, and would like to know which part makes the turtle create the pixel art instantly instead of actually seeing draw it?

Comment: @JacobVoss, normally turtle slows down drawing so you can see it happening, this is called *tracing*.  When I used `tracer(False)` I turned off tracing but then I'm expected to let the system know when to show the user the current state of the drawing, which is the `update()` call.  Other actions can cause an update, so don't assume you have complete control over it.  Make sure you call `update()` when you're ready to have your changes shown to your user.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way would probably be to define a function that draws the shape of a pixel of the proper size at the current turtle position, and then call repeatedly in a pair of nested `for` loops.

Here's an example:

```
import turtle

COLORS = {0: 'white',
          1: 'red',
          2: 'blue',
          3: 'green',
          4: 'black',
          5: 'yellow',
          6: 'orange'}

PIXELS = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 5, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0],
          [0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

WIDTH, HEIGHT = len(PIXELS[0]), len(PIXELS)

scn = turtle.Screen()
pen = turtle.Turtle()

def pixel():
    for i in range(4):
        pen.forward(30)
        pen.left(90)
    pen.forward(30)


if __name__ == "__main__" :
    scn.setup(600, 600)
    pen.speed(0)
    pen.hideturtle()
    for i in range(WIDTH):
        pen.up()
        pen.setpos(0, 30*i)  # Row position.
        pen.down()
        row = PIXELS[i]
        for j in range(HEIGHT):
            col = COLORS[row[j]]
            pen.fillcolor(col)
            pen.begin_fill()
            pixel()
            pen.end_fill()

    print('done - press any key to exit')
    turtle.onkeypress(exit)
    turtle.listen()
    turtle.done()
```

Result:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can define one function called square like this:

```
def square():
       for x in range(4):
             t.forward(20)
             t.right(90)
```

which draws a 20x20 square.

Now you can use it to draw any color like the example below which will make a Horizontal line of 4 pixels, like the Tetris piece:

```
def Tetris_Piece_1():
  for x in range(4):
      t.begin_fill()
      square()
      t.color("Blue")
      t.end_fill()
      t.color("Black")
      t.forward(20)
```

And I think it can't be optimized more than that, Also check this tutorial: (https://replit.com/talk/learn/How-to-draw-Pixel-Art-on-Python-with-Turtle/7556)